# Restore right to user in sql

Tags: sql-server

What access do we need to restore a database.Does db_backupoperator fixed database role have this right? Please let me know.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is the "Permissions" section in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) unclear?